# Exercise 0.8 in Rotman's An Introduction to Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

I have just started working my way through Rotman's An Introduction to Algebraic Topology.

This is the definition of **subcategory** given in the text:

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ be categories with $\mathrm{obj} \; \mathcal{C} \subseteq \mathrm{obj} \;\mathcal{A}$. If $A,B \in \mathrm{obj}   \; \mathcal{C}$, let us denote the two possible Hom sets by $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(A,B)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(A,B)$. Then $\mathcal{C}$ is a **subcategory** of $\mathcal{A}$ if $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(A,B) \subseteq \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(A,B)$ for all $A,B \in \mathrm{obj} \; \mathcal{C}$ and if composition in $\mathcal{C}$ is the same as composition in $\mathcal{A}$; [...]

From this I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> **Exercise 0.8 (ii)**
>   If $\mathcal{C}'$ is a subcategory of $\mathcal{C}$ and if $A \in \mathrm{obj} \; \mathcal{C}'$, then the identity of $A$ in $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}'}(A,A)$ is the identity $1_A$ in $ \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(A,A)$

If we denote the identity of $A$ in $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}'}(A,A)$ by $1_A'$, we have to show that $1_A = 1_A'$.

Obviously $1_A \circ_{\mathcal{C}} 1_A' = 1_A'$ where $\circ_{\mathcal{C}}$ denotes the composition in $\mathcal{C}$. But from that point on I'm stuck, since I can't assume that $1_A \in \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}'}(A,A)$.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Although I enjoy some of Rotman's texts, I would dare say that there are better options to learn algebraic topology from.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subcategory

Comment: Hm. Maybe I should look out for another textbook if the one I'm using now gets an essential definition wrong in Chapter 0.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Just curious: what would be your preferred text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like his definition of subcategory is just wrong. Let $\mathcal C$ be the category with a single object $A$ and two morphisms $1,e$ with $e^2=e.$ Then there is a "subcategory" $\mathcal C'$ with just the morphism $e$ which is then the identity of $A$ in $\mathcal C'.$ The definition of subcategory should include the identities.

Comment: Compare this example to: if $R$ is a ring with a central idempotent element $e$ then $eR$ is a (nonunital) subring with unit $e$.

Comment: Nice (counter)example.